# Why can't my Fedora VM access this shared folder?

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, fedora, network-shares

I have spent the last 6 hours fighting trying to get Fedora 19 as guest OS on Windows 7 SP1 host to successfully access a shared folder. I'm using VirtualBox 4.2.18. Lots and lots of Googling. Yeah, I'm like the millionth schmuck going through this seemingly simple setup, but I'm getting no joy to access my Windows 7 host shared folder from my Fedora guest.

I visit Share Folders config and set Machine access to `D:\workspaces\linux` with a share name of `share`. I do not click `Read Only` or `Automount` checkbox ops.

I fire up Fedora. Log in. Fire up a `Terminal` and type

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/share
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 share /mnt/share
```

Next I add my user to the vboxsf group

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf cphi
```

Finally I attempt to visit the share and list the contents

```
cd /mnt/share
ls -la
```

Nothing?! Actually I never see my prompt again unless I press `Ctrl+C` to exit.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Someone posted a comment earlier that was deleted.  It mentioned that an earlier Fedora 19 kernel version `3.9.5` did work.  `uname -r` for me shows `3.11.1-200.fc19.x86_64`. My Linux skills are not mad.  How do you rollback a kernel version?  If I can't I guess I have to reinstall Fedora. Side note: w/ LinuxMint 15 I was able to reproduce steps above and it worked flawlessly.  Something is amiss w/ my particular combo of versions.

Comment: I have the same setup and get the same behaviour. What is also interesting for me is that I can still access files in the shared folder from the guest VM, and write files to the shared directory, but ls simply will not list the contents of the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of 3.11 kernel, just install beta version of virtualbox and vboxguest additions http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.0_BETA3/

Answer (score 1):

Or set the previous kernel (3.10.11-200) as the default by following the instructions [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2#Setting_default_entry).